# SSRS Report Detailed Trial Balance error "The field with ID '0' does not exist in table 'LedgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp'"

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, ssrs-2008-r2

I've been trying to open a report in the General Ledger > Reports > Detailed trial balance. In the form, I input a parameter for Ledger account.MainAccount. When I click OK, I got an error:

> Error executing code: The field with ID '0' does not exist in table 'LedgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp'.
>
> Stack trace
>
> (S)\Classes\RecordInsertList\add
> (S)\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceDP\populateTmpTransDetail - line 100
> (S)\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceDP\processReportDetail - line 28
> (S)\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceDP\processReport - line 32
> (S)\Classes\SrsReportRunRdpPreProcessService\executeWithContract - line 102
> (S)\Classes\SrsReportRunRdpPreProcessService\executeRDLClasses - line 38
> (C)\Classes\SrsReportRunService\preRunReport - line 26
> (C)\Classes\SrsReportRunImpl\preRunReport - line 12
> (C)\Classes\SrsReportRunController\runReport - line 42
> (C)\Classes\SrsReportRunController\run
> (C)\Classes\SysOperationController\startOperation - line 10
> (C)\Classes\SrsReportRunController\startOperation
> (C)\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceController\main - line 9

If I click ok and again click Select it shows me duplicate of last two line of range.
I am using MS Dynamics AX 2012 R2.
Any help in this situation.

Regards

BSugitayasa

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far? Share your research and debugging results with us.

Comment: I've tried to debug. error occurred in class LedgerTrialBalanceDP in method populateTmpTransDetail().
Error refers to a table LedgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp, but I got there I did not find the clue, when a table will add to the RecordInsertList.

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today, it's a bug. You just need to change the RecordInsertList initialization:

\Classes\LedgerTrialBalanceDP\populateTmpTransDetail, Line 64:

Original line:

> recordInsertList = new
>   RecordInsertList(tableNum(**LedgerTrialBalanceTmp**), true, true, true,
>   true, true, _ledgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp);

Change to:

> recordInsertList = new
>   RecordInsertList(tableNum(**LedgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp**), true,
>   true, true, true, true, _ledgerTrialBalanceStagingTmp);

Compile forward, generate incremental CIL, and it's done.

Cheers

Comment: Dear @Fabio,Thanks for the advice. I have tried and have been successful. About duplicate existing range problem on **\Classes\DimensionProvider\addAttributeRangeToQuery** also been successful in fix. See More discuss in https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/101831/206828.aspx#206828